# Removing specific parts of the image in openCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am doing some image processing and need to do the following task in images ::

**Image**

[image]

From here I want to remove eyes, eyebrows, lips etc such that the smoothness of the image is not lost (eg, if the eyes are removed then the area should be replaced with neighboring colors).

I have the details(Points) of the area covering the part that needs to be flatten(eyes etc).Shown below::

[image]

Comment: Can you share the library you are using to generate the facial feature points ?

Comment: @ZdaR, sure will ask. Do you know how I can achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: @OddNorg Dlib doesn't provides the points on fore-head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the points or even better contours you want to replace (like these drawn in green in your 2nd image), have a look at `inpaint`: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d0d/group__photo.html#gaedd30dfa0214fec4c88138b51d678085

I think this is exactly what you are looking for! See here for an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting

The procedure is pretty simple:

1. Make a mask filled with your contours (`drawContours`, thickness: `CV_FILLED`) to be inpainted/replaced with their respective environment and
2. `inpaint` with this mask.

I should mention that this does only work with 8bit-images.

The following (untested) code snippet should do it.

```
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC1);
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
  drawContours(mask, contours, i, Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED);
Mat dst;
double radius = 20;    
inpaint(img, mask, dst, radius, INPAINT_NS);
//inpaint(img, mask, dst, radius, INPAINT_TELEA);
imshow("dst", dst);
waitKey();
```

Edit: To make a contour of a couple of points:
A contour is just a vector of points, packed into another vector. So, the solution should be something like this with a given `vector<Point> points`.

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
contours.push_back(points);
drawContours(mask, contours, 0, Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED);
```

Comment: My image is a colored BRG image, so do I need to GRAYSCALE to get it 8bit?

Comment: 8bit 1-channel or 3-channel, so it works in your case.

Comment: How can I draw contours along the path that I want, like the ones shown in green dots? Because that is also what I am not able to find as most of the contours are there by default right?

Comment: I thought you already have drawn red dots and green contours, but if not so ... can't you simple take the points as contour?

Comment: The mask should be GrayScaled right? to make it 1 channel?

Comment: Take mask should be ``CV_8UC1`` like in my code snippet, so, yes: 8-bit 1-channel.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The answer was of great help.

Comment: Hi, I am facing problem with inpainting as its not working properly with generic faces as the neighboring pixels are sometimes black.
https://ibb.co/nKcz0v
Like in the image the hair is nearby and it comes up. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Just an idea: Make a subimage with ``Rect`` which excludes the hair, inpaint and copy it back into the original image. Inpainting seems to work at image borders, so that should be possible. More effort is needed to do that automatically which could lead to another question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

A Python version, using simple threshold to select facial features (because I don't have those green contours), then inpainting, as mentioned in Phann's answer:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_inpainted(img):
    gs = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gs, 70, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    mask_features = 1 - thresh #1 for the dark pixels, 0 everywhere else
    #enlarge the mask a little bit...
    mask_features = cv2.dilate(mask_features, np.ones((8, 8), np.uint8))
    return cv2.inpaint(img, mask_features, 8, cv2.INPAINT_NS)

img_source = cv2.imread("test_images/face.jpg")
img_dest = img_source[:]

#manually select two areas of interest
img_dest[158:276, 34:213] = get_inpainted(img_source[158:276, 34:213]) #eyebrows to nostrils
img_dest[278:343, 68:190] = get_inpainted(img_source[278:343, 68:190]) #mouth

cv2.imwrite("test_images/face_inp.jpg", img_dest)
```

And so we turn the guy from your first picture (left) into a faceless scary dude (right):
[image]

Comment: What does this line do :: `mask_features = 1 - thresh` ?

Comment: It inverts the binary mask, calculated at the previous line.

Comment: Hi, I am facing problem with inpainting as its not working properly with generic faces as the neighboring pixels are sometimes black.
https://ibb.co/nKcz0v
Like in the image the hair is nearby and it comes up. Any idea how to solve that?