# How do I remove certain part of an Image in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to isolate only the beans from the container. However, it doesn't seems to work. Please how can I achieve this OpenCV python?

I have use `cv2.inrange()` but I don't seem to get it.

[image]

Comment: The only thing I want right now is just the beans, the white background is useless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing specific parts of the image in openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404318/removing-specific-parts-of-the-image-in-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

This image is what i can give you :

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2

## Read
img = cv2.imread("QdMz0.jpg")
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
mask1 = cv2.inRange(rgb, (56, 0, 0), (70, 255,255))
mask2 = cv2.inRange(rgb, (5,0,0), (36, 255, 255))
## final mask and masked
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)
target = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask)

#cv2.imwrite("target.png", target)
plt.imshow(target)
```